# How do I align textboxes?

Tags: html, css, flask

I'm using the following css code for aligning text, but I also want the boxes themselves to be evenly distributed/aligned so they don't look off. I've tried text-align: center; inline-box,

```
form{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

etc. Any idea how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Try using clear, width, float, and margin.  This might help.  https://jsfiddle.net/durtpwvx/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a specific with for your text in order for you elements to align itself properly. by giving specific with to your text, you are giving the element unified width. However, I suggest you wrap your text and textfield in a container like this:

```css
.form-field {
  /* .text class for your text */
  & > .text {
    width: 200px;
  }
  & > .text-field {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would either solve it with the use of a table or with a grid. As table for styling is an outdated method I would recommend the use of a grid:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

h1, h2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#medRecords {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heart Disease Prediction</h1>
<br>
<h2>Please enter your medical records:</h2>
<br>
<div id="medRecords">
  <div>age</div>
  <div><input type="text"></div>
  <div>sex</div>
  <div><input type="text"></div>
  <div>cp</div>
  <div><input type="text"></div>
  <div>trestbps</div>
  <div><input type="text"></div>
  <div>chol</div>
  <div><input type="text"></div>
  <div>fbs</div>
  <div><input type="text"></div>
  <div>restecg</div>
  <div><input type="text"></div>
  <div>thalach</div>
  <div><input type="text"></div>
  <div>exang</div>
  <div><input type="text"></div>
  <div>oldpeak</div>
  <div><input type="text"></div>
  <div>slope</div>
  <div><input type="text"></div>
  <div>ca</div>
  <div><input type="text"></div>
  <div>thal</div>
  <div><input type="text"></div>
</div>
```